# How to implement lazy load for container class?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, lazy-loading

I found [Lazy load Plugin](https://responsivedesign.is/resources/javascript-jquery/lazy-load-jquery) in internet and used it. It working for only images. I am using bootstrap for designing my website, I like to give lazy load for entire container which having text and images. Please help me to solve this. Demo links would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried anything but since it uses Jquery i'm going to guess that something like the following will do the job!

```
$("div.container").lazyload();
```

**Edited**

```
<div class="container lazy">
content
</div>
${"div.container").lazyload();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I already tried this. But in firebug net tab i cant see anything loading while scrolling.

Comment: Check out the edited version and tell me if it works?